# Wordpress repeatedly shows temporary 404 on all subpages, resolves by itself or updating permalink settings

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks

since a while, wordpress repeatedly shows 404 on all subpages except the homepage.

Its hard to pin down when / how often / how long it happens but in my experience several times a week and it resolves by itself after several minutes or after I manually navigate to settings->permalinks and click "save".

Therefore its hard to troubleshoot by disabling plugins / themes 1by1.

What I tried so far:

- Flushing the server or browser cache does not solve the problem
- Logged in and logged out users are effected
- Also in inkognito browser and different browsers / devices
- Backend works fine during the 404s

Further Infos

- The application runs on nginx.
- Console shows an ERR ABORTED 404 for instantpage.js while 404 shows (guess this is related to the feature "url preloading" form the performance plugin perfmatters -> could this be the cause or only a symptom?)
- Could not find any helpful entries in debug.log or nginx error log.
- Potential responsible plugins installed:

Elementor
Runcloud Hub
Cloudflare
WpRocker
prettylinks

Ive found the following script here (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/recurring-404-error-for-all-pages-but-not-posts-or-bbpress-topics/) to log 404 and flush permalinks with transients:

---

```
function do_stuff_on_404(){
    if( is_404() ){
        global $wp;
        $check = get_transient( 'permalinks_flushed_recently' );
        if ( $check === false ) {
            flush_rewrite_rules();
        set_transient( 'permalinks_flushed_recently', 'yes', 5 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
        error_log('['.date("F j, Y, g:i a e O").']'.home_url( $wp->request )."\n", 3, "/404-demon-bug.log");
            wp_redirect(home_url( $wp->request ));
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'do_stuff_on_404' );
```

---

But it seems not to work - there are no entries in the log file and it does not resolve the 404 automatically.

I am not an experiences programmer, but could this be due to the wrong file path or missing rights?

Ive pasted the snippet in function.php and my directory structure looks like the following:
"/home/applicationname/webapps/applicationname/wp-content/...."

I created the file "404-demon-bug.log" (rights 664) manually in the wordpress root directory and also under themes/themename/

External monitor tools?
Can anyone recommend an external tool / service that could track those temporary 404 (probably in 1-minute interval?)
Seems not to work with my current setup with uptimerobot, managewp or google analytics, search console, SEO Yoast...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards